# Ubuntu not responding to mouse clicks in Virtual PC 2007

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, microsoft-virtual-pc

I successfully installed Ubuntu on Virtual PC 2007.  It works fine for a while, but after some period of inactivity I return to the VM and Ubuntu doesn't respond to mouse clicks.  At least that's what it feels like.  The mouse moves and the clock continues to update, but it doesn't respond to any of my clicks.

Are there any settings or tweaks needed to keep the mouse working in Ubuntu under Virtual PC 2007?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar problems using anything other than windows with VPC2007.   Do you have to use VPC?  I've had GREAT success with [Sun Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).   Free and is IMHO a  much better product.

Comment: +1 VirtualBox is definitely a better option for virtualizing Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching off desktop effects. I've seen all sorts of weird problems kick in with desktop effects are enabled.

I agree with @NoCarrier; VirtualBox is well worth a try.